# React-Leaflet tiles have different contrast?

Tags: leaflet, geoserver, react-leaflet

When using leaflet-react WMSTileLayer (with Geoserver as the WMS server) I appear to have different contrasts for the various tiles, creating visible 'borders' between tiles as below.

Leaflet-React:

[image]

If i use the layer view within Geoserver i get a nice flat set of tiles.

Built-in GeoServer viewer:

[image]

I'm using a very simple example just as a test for now:
[image]

I'm not super up to speed with all of the intricacies of react, or leaflet, so I have struggled a bit with the leaflet-react docs, so I've likely missed something pretty simple, for example I haven't found out how to use png instead of jpeg.

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days, I decide to post. Then solve it 2 hours later.

Issue here is due to GeoServer (helpfully) applying its own ColorMap to each tile that is being requested. Solution is to specify a fixed ColorMap in the relevant Style:

```
<ColorMap>
        <ColorMapEntry color="#323232" quantity="-300" label="label1" opacity="1"/>
        <ColorMapEntry color="#BBBBBB" quantity="200" label="label2" opacity="1"/>
</ColorMap>
```

Solution from here:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308217/geotiff-rendered-in-openlayers-using-geoserver-tiles-have-different-brightness